# change image transition timeout

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to work out some of the variables of a JQuery-based scripts I got here: http://www.dreamcss.com/2009/04/create-beautiful-jquery-sliders.html

Specifically I'm trying to work out how to change the delay between slide transition, whether I can disable the auto-transitioning or not (and how), and how to change the sliding speed of the images. Which variables do they rely on? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Can you include a bit of code directly in your question to better highlight where you're having troubles? (If people stumble upon your question in the future it won't rely on the external source still being available.)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like all 3 of those things are controlled within scripts.js.

Slide delay is variable `at` on line 76, and you can see that it defaults to 10 seconds (10 * 1000 milliseconds). It's used down on line 94 to control the delay for the `setTimeout` call that switches to the next slide.

Auto-transitioning is `ar` on line 77, and can be disabled by changing its value to false. You can see that in the `auto` function on line 96, the first thing that is checked is whether `ar` is true. If it's not, then it bails out before performing the transition.

The slide animation speed is on line 113, `$('#'+d[i].id).stop().animate({left:((i-pos)*1000)},1000,'swing');`. That 2nd 1000 is the duration property for the animate function, and it's set to 1 second (1000 ms). So change the value right before 'swing'.